# bbswitch failing to turn of Nvidia GPU (Refused to change power state, currently in D0)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, bbswitch

I've noticed that my laptop has been running hotter than it should be as well as output similar to the following from `dmesg` around when `bbswitch` should be shutting down my Nvidia GPU

```
[ 5775.721636] NVLINK: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 248
[ 5775.721996] [drm] Module unloaded
[ 5775.747097] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[ 5775.747109] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20141107/nsarguments-95)
[ 5775.761965] pci 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D0
```

Based on this, it appears that bbswitch is failing to actually turn off the GPU

For reference, output of `lspci | grep 01:00`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev ff)
```

Bumblebee is working correctly aside from this issue. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [BumbleBee bug #664](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/664):

> This is harmless and known from the beginning. From what I remember,
>   this is due to trying to power OFF the card too fast or something like
>   that. I’ll keep this issue opened (but cleaned a bit your messages to
>   keep only related content) so that we think about either fixing this
>   or properly document it.